# PHP: intval() equivalent for numbers >= 2147483647

Tags: php, types, numbers, integer

In PHP 5, I use intval() whenever I get numbers as an input. This way, I want to ensure that I get no strings or floating numbers. My input numbers should all be in whole numbers. But when I get numbers >= 2147483647, the signed integer limit is crossed.

What can I do to have an intval() equivalent for numbers in all sizes?

Here's what I want to have:

```
<?php
$inputNumber = 3147483647.37;
$intNumber = intvalEquivalent($inputNumber);
echo $intNumber; // output: 3147483647
?>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: Based on some answers, I've tried to code an equivalent function. But it doesn't work exactly as intval() does yet. How can I improve it? What is wrong with it?

```
function intval2($text) {
    $text = trim($text);
    $result = ctype_digit($text);
    if ($result == TRUE) {
        return $text;
    }
    else {
        $newText = sprintf('%.0f', $text);
        $result = ctype_digit($newText);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            return $newText;
        }
        else {
             return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work in it and what's wrong with other solutions here, including the regex one?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this function, it will properly remove any decimal as intval does and remove any non-numeric characters.

```
<?php
function bigintval($value) {
  $value = trim($value);
  if (ctype_digit($value)) {
    return $value;
  }
  $value = preg_replace("/[^0-9](.*)$/", '', $value);
  if (ctype_digit($value)) {
    return $value;
  }
  return 0;
}

// SOME TESTING
echo '"3147483647.37" : '.bigintval("3147483647.37")."<br />";
echo '"3498773982793749879873429874.30872974" : '.bigintval("3498773982793749879873429874.30872974")."<br />";
echo '"hi mom!" : '.bigintval("hi mom!")."<br />";
echo '"+0123.45e6" : '.bigintval("+0123.45e6")."<br />";
?>
```

Here is the produced output:

```
"3147483647.37" : 3147483647
"3498773982793749879873429874.30872974" : 3498773982793749879873429874
"hi mom!" : 0
"+0123.45e6" : 0
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This function is potentially harmfull when dealing with negative numbers:  while `intval(-100) == -100`, `bigintval(-100) == 0`.

Answer (score 6):

you can also use regular expressions to remove everything after the intial numeric parts:

```
<?php
$inputNumber = "3147483647.37";
$intNumber = preg_replace('/^([0-9]*).*$/', "\\1", $inputNumber);
echo $intNumber; // output: 3147483647
?>
```

Comment: I think there's an error with your regex, your code does not output anything at all.

Comment: Thank you! :) Your answer was important since Dustin Fineout used your regexp ...

Comment: Actually the regex I use is slightly different :p

Answer (score 2):

Either use `number_format($inputNumber, 0, '', '')`

Or if you only want to check if its a whole number then use `ctype_digit($inputNumber)`

Don't use the proposed `is_numeric`, as also floats are numeric. e.g. *"+0123.45e6"* gets accepted by `is_numeric`

Comment: float will still overflow this.

Comment: Float overflow doesn't matter, so it seems to be useful. Please see my edit in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to number_format, you can use sprintf:

```
sprintf("%.0f", 3147483647.37) // 3147483647
```

However, both solutions suffer from float overflow, for example:

```
sprintf("%.0f", 314734534534533454346483647.37) // 314734534534533440685998080
```

Comment: Thank you! Please have a look at my edit in the question. Is this a good equivalent function?

Comment: @Artem: Not only does it suffer from float overflow, it also does rounding. sprintf("%.0f", 1.5) returns 2, while intval(1.5) returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle arbitrary-precision numbers, you will need to use the [gmp](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) extension. The function [`gmp_init()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-init.php), for example, converts a string to a gmp resource object. the drawback is that you must use other functions of that extension to further process that object. Converting it back to a string is done using [`gmp_strval()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-strval.php), for example.

```
$gmpObject = gmp_init($string, 10);
if ($gmpObject === FALSE) {
    # The string was not a valid number,
    # handle this case here
}
echo gmp_strval($gmpObject);
```

You might want to only *verify* that the string is representing a valid number and use the string itself, if you do not intend to do any operations on the value. That can be done using a regular expression:

```
$containsInt = preg_match('/^\d+$/', $string);
# Or for floating point numbers:
$containsFloat = preg_match('/^\d+(.\d+)?$/', $string);
echo $string;
```

Another option is to use [`is_numeric()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). But that function does more conversion than you might like. Quoting from docs of that function:

> ... +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = 453453445435.4;

echo $bigint = floor($a);
```