# Typecasting vs function to convert variable type in PHP

Tags: php, casting

Is there any difference between typecasting and using a function to convert a variable to some type?

`(float)$var` VS. `floatval($var)`

If there are, when one of those should be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

There's no difference in the resulting value, just:

- `(float)` is a language feature and very quick
- `floatval()` incurs the overhead of a function call (minimal, but nonetheless...)
- `floatval()` as a function can be used in ways that `(float)` cannot, e.g. `array_map('floatval', $foo)`

The last point is, I believe, the main reason for `floatval`'s existence: so each casting operation has a function equivalent, which can be useful in some circumstances.