# How to write float with Twig?

Tags: php, twig

How to write float with Twig?

```
if((float)$a == (float)$b) {
echo true;
} else {
echo false;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Doing `(float) $a` is basically the same as `floatval($a)` (see [Typecasting vs function to convert variable type in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940148/typecasting-vs-function-to-convert-variable-type-in-php)).

Twig doesn't natively have a `floatval` function, but you can add it yourself. Add this code to register a function or a filter. You can of course register both if you want. Add the code e.g. near where `$twig` is defined.

```
$twig->addFunction(new \Twig_Function('floatval', 'floatval'));

$twig->addFilter(new \Twig_Filter('floatval', 'floatval'));
```

As the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters) says:

> The first argument passed to the `Twig_Filter` constructor is the name of the filter you will use in templates and the second one is the PHP callable to associate with it.
>
> ...
>
> Functions are defined in the exact same way as filters, but you need to create an instance of `Twig_Function`.

Then you can use the new function in Twig like this:

```
{% if floatval(a) == floatval(b) %}
    {{ true }}
{% else %}
    {{ false }}
{% endif %}

{# Shorter: #}
{{ floatval(a) == floatval(b) ? true : false }}
```

Or using the new filter:

```
{% if a|floatval == b|floatval %}
    {{ true }}
{% else %}
    {{ false }}
{% endif %}

{# Shorter: #}
{{ a|floatval == b|floatval ? true : false }}
```